# Odoo 8 Qweb report header won't hide

Tags: xml, pdf, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I don't want the automatic header and footer to appear on my pdf reports and they always appear no matter what I do. I removed them on the settings and they are still there. I can make them disappear on the html report but on the pdf the header is always there. But for the footer I succeeded to make it disappear by declaring a custom footer 
`<div class="footer"/>` but `<div class="header"/>` doesn't work to hide the header. I tried by setting the header invisible with css but on the pdf the header is still there. Can someone help me please?

Comment: show us how you declared your report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have used **<t t-call="report.external_layout">**
then remove it.

So, Headers and Footers are not appear in report but if you want to set paper layout for setup top/bottom margin then you can set-up from
Settings >> Technical >> Reports >> Paper Format

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to delete that line.

div class="header

after delete that header tab, from report it will be removed.